# iOS Launch screens with logic

Tags: ios, swift, launch-screen

Is it possible to build some logic into the iOS launch screen storyboard?

I want a 'splash' screen showing the title, only when the user launches my app for the first time.

Then in subsequent launches, I'd like the launch screen to have an empty navigation controller.

(If there's a way to do this programmatically/outside of storyboard/IB, more than happy to do this too).

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642016/execute-code-in-launch-screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible. The launch screen is not rendered by your app, but by the system, so it is static.

> Note that the launch screen is is not a fully customizable view controller. You cannot specify a custom class name in the storyboard and expect the system to give you the option to execute code at this stage by calling viewDidLoad. Remember, the app hasn’t launched yet.

(According to [this site](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/))

Also it appears that you cannot change the launch image programatically, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027960/change-splash-screen-image-programmatically).

Comment: Trying to change the launch image programmatically would change the contents of your application bundle which would invalidate the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 Version 8.3.2 (8E2002), I try add ViewController to LaunchScreen.storyboard but func viewDidLoad() not call, You can add FakeLaunchScreen.storyboard, layout the same LaunchScreen.storyboard  and do something your like.

[image]