# How can I specify text in iOS to be white if the device is in dark mode and black if in light mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, ios-darkmode

I am working on a launchscreen.  The following code is used to select a dark or white background depending on the device mode settings:

```
 <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
```

But how can I set a light or dark background for my text that also changes depending on the device mode settings:

```
<label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Test" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="EcF-nC-k2o">
    <rect key="frame" x="137.5" y="309.5" width="100" height="48"/>
    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="40"/>
    <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
</label>
```

Hoping someone can give good advice on this because I spent a lot of time researching and could not find any suggestions at all.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Launchscreens are static and will be rendered by the system not by your app. [See this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820589/ios-launch-screens-with-logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set it to "Label Color" in Interface Builder, the system is automatically setting an appropriate color based on the interface style (light or dark).

Check out the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color#dynamic-system-colors) for a reference of the available dynamic colors.